# Timing out on mount nfs command

Tags: linux, networking, nfs

I am following this guide to set up an NFS server, with the exception that I have completely disabled my firewall: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-20-04

I have a worker machine on IP address `10.0.0.8`, and my file server is on `149.210.143.92`. After running the following console command:

`mount -v 149.210.143.92:/mnt/kubernetes-nfs-volume /var/kubernetes-nfs-volume`

I get the following output:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for [some date 2 minutes from now]
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=149.210.143.92,clientaddr=10.0.0.8'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

The folders I'm trying to mount exist, and I can succesfully ping and ssh from my worker machine to the file server. So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think its just due to the mount command , try this one :

```
mount -t nfs 149.210.143.92:/mnt/kubernetes-nfs-volume /var/kubernetes-nfs-volume
```

Comment: Adding the @ creates a "failed to resolve server" error.

Comment: @yesman i edited now , you can check it